if an entity depends on two other entities(that have a relationship between them) should I make the enitity depend on the relationship instead?
If I have three entities (end-user, country, tier) in my system that has relationships as follows:

Where each country has its own tiers with specified points per year, and each end-user has a country and can subscribe to tiers in that country by paying the specified points.
For example, Lets say we have tiers:

Free tier
Silver tier
Gold tier
Premium tier

Furthermore, we have a country Qatar that has the following tiers:

Free tier --> 0 points per year
Silver tier --> 20 points per year
Gold tier --> 40 points per year

Also, we an end-user that is located in Qatar, that is firstly subscribed to the Free tier with 0 points per year, then when he aquires 20 points he can upgrade to Silver tier by paying the required 20 points for the Silver tier in Qatar
What is the best way to design such relationships in the database considering the following:

We want to save each tier that the end-user has subscribed to
The points per year for each tier in each country could change and
we want to save the amount that the end-user has payed when he
subscribed to the tier in the specified country

Is it better to link the end-user directely to country-tier relationship entity
or to link end-user to country and tier as in the previous picture considering that the end-user should have one country and can't change that country?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Database normalization should prevent weird states of data. For example, a properly normalized database should prevent a user being in the USA, but assigned a Tier associated with Brazil. It doesn't make sense for a user located in the USA to be associated with the Premium Tier in Brazil — unless that is a desired outcome based on the business rules.
To fix this:

Remove the foreign key relationship between End-User and Countries.
Remove the foreign key relationship between End-User_Tiers and Tiers.
Add a foreign key relationship from End-User_Tiers to Country_Tiers

The country a user is in would be derived from the Country_Tier they are associated with. This prevents data anomalies like "Greg lives in the USA but is assigned to the Premium Tier in Brazil."
While this design follows better data normalization, it presents a challenge in the user interface of your application. I assume the end user would choose which country they live in, or perhaps you can discover this based on their IP address and geo location. It would be awkward to present the user with 100 Tiers from all nations and ask them to choose the Tier for the country in which they live. This becomes a usability issue. Instead, have the user choose their country (or find some way to choose it for them).
The country selected in the user interface is then used to filter the Tiers available to them. Upon saving this information to the database, you insert a row into the End-User_Tiers table pointing to the record in Country_Tiers that matches the selected country and selected Tier.
The corrected data model is below:


The answer has removed the constraint for an end-user to be scoped to a specific country. This could only ever be enforced if there was already a selected tier for the user. It is unclear whether the model needs to permit a state whereby a user has not yet selected a tier but is inherently scoped to a country. If so, this answer is not correct for that scenario. "each end-user has a country and can subscribe to tiers in that country by paying the specified points." suggests that end-user creation and tier registration are two separate stages.

To phrase it more directly for OP: can an end-user exist with no active subscriptions? can an end-user subscribe to different tiers in different countries (either concurrently or consecutively)? If the answer to either question is no, then this answer doesn't fit.

I understood the question differently. I did not see an obvious sign that user registration and tier assignment needed to be different operations or stages. Even if they currently are, I would challenge the assumption that the country for the user needs to be assigned early on, but this is a business decision. It should follow business process, not some Visio jocky with a data model diagram (i.e. "me").

"each end-user has a country and can subscribe to tiers in that country" suggests two separate steps. However, I agree that this isn't proven, but rather that OP would need to clarify. The question currently leaves it unconfirmed either way.
